# SQL move content from 1 table to another based where row id

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

i have 2 tables in my mysql database and i need to move content from 1 column to another column in a 2nd table where the key is the same.

As the example
table 1 (o8hcn_j_content) has a column called jr_businessdescription.

I want to move the entries in this column into a column named fulltext in a 2nd table called (o8hcn_content)
The tables don't have entries in teh same order so i want to match this update where the field in the first table (o8hcn_j_content) called contentid matches the id field of table 2.

I've tried lots of ways here are the three I had thought would work but didn't:

```
UPDATE o8hcn_content SET fulltext = (o8hcn_j_content.jr_businessdescription FROM o8hcn_jreviews_content t2 WHERE o8hcn_j_content.contentid = o8hcn_content.id)

UPDATE o8hcn_content 
SET o8hcn_content.fulltext=o8hcn_j_content.jr_businessdescription,  
WHERE o8hcn_content.id=o8hcn_j_content.contentid;

UPDATE o8hcn_content
SET o8hcn_content.fulltext=o8hcn_j_content.jr_businessdescription
FROM o8hcn_content
INNER JOIN o8hcn_jreviews_content
ON o8hcn_content.id=o8hcn_j_content.contentid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct MySQL syntax is:

```
UPDATE o8hcn_content JOIN
       o8hcn_jreviews_content
       ON o8hcn_content.id = o8hcn_j_content.contentid
    SET o8hcn_content.fulltext = o8hcn_j_content.jr_businessdescription;
```